# Openshift run cron with an invalid python version

Tags: python, cron, openshift

Two days ago my cron jobs stopped working. In the cron log is an error loading a library, so I change the cron to only make a "python --version" and shows 2.6 when my cardtrige is Python 2.7.

If I try to load the vritenv in the cron fails to, because don't foun Python 2.7 libs. But if I enter by ssh and run the bash in the crom, the code run perfect.

Anyone knows what happens?

EDIT:

I reported the bug and they are working on it https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1076626

Comment: I'm running a python 3.3 app on openshift. My cron jobs stopped running also several days ago. I posted here but nobody has responded. There seems to be push problems also.

Comment: looks like a bug. They are working on them https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1076626

Answer (score 1):

Seems that the bug is in the cron cartridge.

I am experiencing this issue in my Ruby 1.9 cartridge too. It shows Ruby 1.8 when running a cron script with ruby --version.

Tried the workaround and exported the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH. It works, and it shows ruby 1.9.3p448 in the cron script now.

Thanks @moisesgallego. I updated the bug report too.

Answer (score 0):

Exists a Workaround explained here: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1076626#c7 until the bug is fixed