# Cronjob in Openshift stopped working

Tags: ruby, cron, redhat, openshift

I have a cronjob running in Openshift which was fine until some days ago, now all of a sudden it stopped working.
This is the script:
fetch_feeds

```
. /usr/bin/rhcsh
pushd ${OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR} > /dev/null
bundle exec rake fetch_feeds RACK_ENV="production"
popd > /dev/null
```

Execute bit is set. It worked the whole time, I did not push updates to the app. I can login via ssh and execute it manually

```
cd app-root/repo/.openshift/cron/hourly/
sh ./fetch_feeds
```

Logs say

```
/var/lib/openshift/xxxxxx/app-root/runtime/repo//.openshift/cron/hourly/fetch_feeds: line 3: bundle: No such file or directory
```

but if I cd into the directory and execute `bundle` it works.
Force-stopping and starting the app did not work. I don't want to recreate the app because I will lose some settings. Any idea what else I can do? Thanks!

EDIT:
Deleting and re-adding the cron-cartridge did not change anything.

EDIT2: Rebuild the application from scratch with the same instructions, it works.  Seems like some update to the Openshift Platform borked something in my app. I still would like to know what happened but I don't know where to look at.

Comment: I am having the same problem with python 3.3 app cron jobs. Openshift made some changes around March 13.  So far, I have found 2 problems and only have one answer.  First, they changed/renamed/removed the old file that started the virtual env (activate_virtenv).  You now just use 'source activate'.  Since I changed that I get a new problem - python: error while loading shared libraries: libpython3.3m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory.  I'm trying to track this down now.  I'm not sure if it's a bug (people have posted current Cron bug)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the logs seem to be saying that the bundle command cannot be found. Meaning the bundler gem is not installed or something.

It should be related to this [question in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22411532/openshift-run-cron-with-an-invalid-python-version/22485136#22485136). You can follow the link within to the OpenShift Bug Report.

The problem is that with the previous OpenShift update, the Ruby 1.9 cartridge is supposed to be using Ruby 1.9.3 but it somehow got changed to Ruby 1.8 instead. Thus, many of the gems installed with Ruby 1.9 will not be found when it is using Ruby 1.8. The workaround is to export the PATH and LD_LIBRARY_PATH in the cron script (refer to the bug report).

Noticed you tried again so the bugfix might have been pushed out to OpenShift already. Not too sure about that.

Nice to see a fellow stringer user here. :)

Comment: Thanks! That fixed it. Exported $LD_LIBRARY_PATH and $PATH within the script and it is running properly again. So developercorey had a similar answer but I was confused and ran the exports on the shell and not in the script itself. So the bounty is yours because you have a more detailed answer. And yes, stringer rocks. :)

Answer (score 1):

These are some commands I needed to run for my papertrailapp cartridge, you might need to do something similar

https://github.com/openshift-cartridges/openshift-papertrailapp-cartridge/blob/master/bin/setup

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

export PATH=/opt/rh/ruby193/root/bin:$PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/rh/ruby193/root/usr/lib64
mkdir $OPENSHIFT_PAPERTRAILAPP_DIR/logs
cd $OPENSHIFT_PAPERTRAILAPP_DIR && bundle install
```

Comment: What is ```$OPENSHIFT_PAPERTRAILAPP_DIR```? Is this a name you randomly thought up or does this follow a scheme? There are env-variables like ```OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR``` & ```OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME```...Thanks in advance!

Comment: you probably want to use your OPENSHIFT_REPO_DIR if that is where your feed rake task lives.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. This does not work unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Have you checked the security context?

`ps -Z` to see what the context is for your process then check the permissions on the directory `ls -Z` to make sure the context is appropriate.

Comment: Looks the same to me. Anything specific to look at? ```unconfined_u:system_r:openshift_t:s0:c4,c12```for the process and ```unconfined_u:object_r:openshift_var_lib_t:s0:c4,c12 fetch_feeds```for the script

Comment: actually they're different, the process has openshift_t and the directories have openshift_var_lib_t. That doesn't seem wrong though, you can try and change the directory to  openshift_t using chcon and see if that works.